# KNN.reg is returning N/A

Tags: r, knn

So I am trying to complete this homework assignment for a CS class and my code has no values for R pred. I created a function to normalize it and standardize the data set. I removed columns that have an N/A. I tries only running one K value and still nothing. Here's the code

```
pacman::p_load(GGally,FNN)

standardize <-
  function(x){
    return((x - mean(x))/sd(x))
 }


knn_2000_stan <-
 set_2000|>
  mutate(across(.cols = where(is.numeric),
                .fns = standardize))

normalize <-
 function(x){
 return((x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)))
}

knn_2000_norm <- set_2000 |>
  mutate(across(.cols = where(is.numeric),
                .fns = normalize))

grid_results <- data.frame(k = numeric(), stan = numeric(), norm = numeric())

# perform grid search for k
for (k in 0:50) {

  knn_norm <- knn.reg(train = knn_2000_norm|>
                        select( Life.expectancy, Measles, under.five.deaths, HIV.AIDS),
         y = life_ex$Life.expectancy,
          k = k)
  r2_norm <- knn_2000_norm$R2Pred
  
  # use caret package to perform kNN with normalized variables
  knn_stan <- knn.reg(train =  knn_2000_stan|>
                        select(Life.expectancy, Measles, under.five.deaths, HIV.AIDS),
                      y = life_ex$Life.expectancy,
                      k = k)
  r2_stan<- knn_2000_stan$R2Pred
  
  # append results to data frame
  grid_results <- grid_results %>%
    add_row(k = k, stan = r2_stan, norm = r2_norm)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to source `R2Pred` from the wrong place.

For example, instead of these lines:

```
r2_norm <- knn_2000_norm$R2Pred
r2_stan<- knn_2000_stan$R2Pred
```

Try this instead:

```
r2_norm <- knn_norm$R2Pred
r2_stan<- knn_stan$R2Pred
```